# How should I set up the postman to test API for python request.post method

Tags: python, python-3.x, postman

I have written my python code as below

```
import requests

# URL
url = 'http://localhost:5000/api'

question = 'what is this'

r = requests.post(url,json={'input':question})
print(r.json())
```

The code is to send a question to an NLP server and return the json of answer.

How should I set up my postman to test it? 
I copied the url into "Enter request URL" tab, and change the tab on the left to "POST". And what else I should do? Where should I type in my input?

Answer (score 1):

To perform a POST request with JSON on Postman:

1. Select POST method
2. Add your URL
3. Click on Body tab and select "raw" radio button
4. A new dropdown will be displayed, with "Text" default value - click it and select JSON(application/json) - This will automatically add a new header(Content-Type: application/json) - you can check it in the Headers tab
5. Add your JSON payload into the text box under the Body tab
6. Click Send button

Note: This is a basic request. Other requests could also require more information - e.g. authorization headers, so make sure you have all the information first

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the question in the body of the request. Start by adding the json header. Click under header and add Content-Type as key and application/json as value.

Then click on body and add input as key and the question as value